# PowerBi seems to lose state of connection depending on the field I pick

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]I have a model with multiple tables. Four tables:

Two tables:

```
FactLocation
DimLocation
```

Are connected on:

```
LocationKey
```

And two more tables:

```
FactPurchaseOrder
DimPurchaseOrder
```

Are connected on:

```
PoKey
```

In addition:

```
DimLocation
FactPurchaseOrder
```

Are also connected on:

```
LocationKey
```

I have a table view, that I would like to use columns from all tables for.

I started out adding items from

```
FactLocation
dimLocation
```

everything was going fine. Then I added one column from

```
FactPurchaseOrder[OrderQuantity]
```

And that went fine. Then I tried to add:

```
FactPurchaseOrder[OrderDate]
```

Initially, I see that it recognized the date format, and it shows me, under Values, the OrderDate and underneath it Year, Quarter, Month, Day fields, but I also get the following error message, inside the Table visual:

```
Can't display the visual
Relationship Detection
There is a missing relationship between these fields. Use autodetect to search for relationship, or create them manually.
```

If I click on autodetect, it tells me No relationships were detected.

The same happens to the other columns from that table.

Any idea what I should be looking for? there is a relationship between the tables, and at least one field was allowed.

Comment: Can you show your relationship diagram?

Comment: Model added to the question